# Induction inequality in the study of the recursive sequence $x_{n+1}=6\frac{1+x_n}{7+x_n}$ with $0<x_1<2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, induction

Given the recursive sequence $x_{n+1}=6\frac{1+x_n}{7+x_n}$ with $0<x_1<2$, show by induction that $0<x_n<2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$.

My try: by hypothesis it is $0<x_1<2$, hence the case for $n=1$ holds. Assume by induction that $0<x_k<2$, so it is both $1<1+x_k<3$ and $7<7+x_k<9$. In the latter inequality, all is positive so I can take the reciprocals and get $\frac{1}{9} < \frac{1}{7+x_k}<\frac{1}{7}$.

Since $6(1+x_k)$ is positive too, multiplying by $6(1+x_k)$ in $\frac{1}{9} < \frac{1}{7+x_k} < \frac{1}{7}$ leads to $\frac{2}{3}(1+x_k) < x_{k+1}<\frac{6}{7}(1+x_k)$.

But as said before, it is $1<1+x_k<3$, so $\frac{2}{3} <\frac{2}{3}(1+x_k) < x_{k+1}<\frac{6}{7}(1+x_k) < \frac{18}{7}$; of course I am wrong, because the function $f(x)=6\frac{1+x}{7+x}$ is such that $\frac{6}{7}<f(x)<2$ for $0<x<2$.

I don't understand where I am making mistake, probably I didn't flip correctly an inequality, but I can't see where. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any mistake in your work. The function $f(x)$ lying between $\frac 67$ and $2$, how does that prove you wrong? Notice that this interval lies completely inside $\frac 23$ and $\frac {18}{7}$. However, your inequality, as of yet isn't strong enough to get to the required proof.

Comment: Hint: consider $x_{n+1}-2=\frac{6+6x_n}{7+x_n}-2=\frac{4x_n-8}{1+7x_n}=\frac{4(x_n-2)}{1+7x_n}$. Now use Ind. Hyp. to get $x_{n+1}-2<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in my comment, there is no mistake in your work.

Here's one possible way to complete the inductive step:
$$x_{n+1}=6-\frac {36}{7+x_n}$$
Now find the range of values that $x_{n+1}$ can take if $0<x_n<2$. Make use of the fact that this is a strictly increasing function in $x_n$. You'll immediately find that the inequality $0<x_{n+1}<2$ holds too.

Comment: Thank you! So now it is $0<x_n<2 \iff 7<7+x_n<9 \iff \frac{1}{9}<\frac{1}{7+x_n}<\frac{1}{7} \iff 4 < \frac{36}{7+x_n} <\frac{36}{7} \iff$
$\iff -\frac{36}{7}<-\frac{36}{7+x_n}<-4 \iff \frac{6}{7}<6-\frac{36}{7+x_n}<2$. So there wasn't an actual mistake in my attempt but the inequality I've found isn't sufficient for what I wanted to prove. Writing $x_{n+1}$ as you've suggested, instead, leads to the desired result. I didn't know this could happen, but I suppose it is like everything else in math that sometimes writing same thing in different forms can be crucial to solve a problem.